# Error When Creating and Editing Product

Tags: product, error

> a:5:{i:0;s:80:"Source model "productslider/source_feature" not found
>   for attribute "is_feature"";i:1;s:3510:"

Comment: Please post the content of the following file: var/report/1339988016645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for `productslider` extension in your project

If you have deleted it, then you'd uninstall `is_feature` attribute from database

If extension is still enabled, then you'd reinstall it, as there is one model missing

Comment: Good solution. Its worked for me. Actually i uninstalled that product slider extension. after get your solution, i reinstalled that extension. Now problem solved. TnQ.

Answer (score 1):

Create `test.php` file at magento root and add bellow code in file and run this file in your browser 
like `http://exaple.com/test.php`

```
<?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app('admin');

    class AR
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
            $installer->startSetup();
            $installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product','is_feature');
            $installer->endSetup();        
        }

    }

    $obj = new AR();
    $obj->index();
    ?>
```